# Python: Issue with modules in package importing each other

Tags: python, package, python-import

Path structure:

```
base.py
my_module/
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    mod2.py
```

base.py:

```
from my_module.mod2 import *
mod2_func2() # This call will work
```

my_module/mod1.py:

```
from mod2 import *

def mod1_func():
    mod2_func1("Hello World") # This call will not work.
```

my_module/mod2.py:

```
from mod1 import *

def mod2_func1(input_text):
    print(input_text)

def mod2_func2():
    mod1_func() # This call will work
```

This code will error out because mod2_func1 is not defined. If I run mod1.py directly (i.e. adding code to an `__name__=="__main__"` block, it will work fine.

This is a reduced example of my real problem, which involves a bunch of modules inside a package all needing to talk to each other like this. The main thing is ensuring that mod1 and mod2 can access each others contents in the local namespace irrespective of which is called from base. I've looked at a ton of documentation on python namespace stuff, importing, and packages and while I'm relieved to find that it seems frustrating to everyone, I haven't found a solution. Any advice?

Comment: There are a few strategies for dealing with cyclic dependencies -- but most of the time, the best strategy is to refactor the code such that the dependency cycles go away... You'll likely end up with easier to maintain code in the long-run.

Comment: Essentially I am interested in mod1, mod2, and others in the package being the same file -- the reason I split them into multiple files is for legibility, even though each part of the split depends on the others. Are you saying the correct behaviour here is to re-merge them into a single enormous file? It seems like there ought to be a simple way to consider them all in the same namespace.

Comment: If you really need to import *everything* from `mod1` into `mod2` and vice versa, the two modules should be merged into one.

Comment: @aaron -- Perhaps having them in a single enormous file is the best thing.  It's hard to give concrete advise without seeing the code and having the background to understand it... In my experience, you can frequently find more reasonable boundaries on which to split things such that the cyclic dependencies go away and the code feels organized.  However, if that isn't the case here then perhaps 1 big module is the correct solution.  e.g. you say that you want to consider them as a single module/namespace -- That's a red flag (How do you know where to look when you need to hunt down the code?).

Comment: "The main thing is ensuring that mod1 and mod2 can access each others contents in the local namespace" - I strongly recommend abandoning that goal. It's not at all worth the pain.

Comment: @ekhumoro It's not necessarily everything, but enough that I would not want to enumerate on both sides. (mgilson) In real life, one submodule is about web browsing/scraping, the other submodule is about user authentication. Sometimes the scraping module requires auth info, sometimes the auth process requires a scrape.

Comment: Alternatively, put all the functions that call each other in one module, and put everything else in a "common" or "utils" module.

Comment: @mgilson: "Perhaps having them in a single enormous file is the best thing" - no way __ever__ - I refactored an app that had one 20k and one 30k file - took me 3 years. @ questioner - you need to refactor - do it now. Consider transient local imports